Need to know compatible derailleur to my Shimano RD-M3000 Acera 9 Speed
It’s a 2019 Raleigh E-Bike Detour
I have two of these bikes and could not figure out why shifting to high gears would get no response on first click then jump 2 on the next click.
Going to low gears was perfect.
Cleaned lubed lines. Same issue.
Finally I swapped derailleurs and the problem went with the derailleur.
So I’d like to go up a notch or two or 3.
It has a mega 9 lite shifter.
I don’t know the size of the cage but my guess is medium.
Difference in prices on derailers is peanuts.
But I want one that will just drop in.
Any suggestions?
How do I know what cage I have?


If not aiming at the lowest expense, without spending too much either, modern entry-level and mid-range components are not that expensive, and a derailleur/cassette/shifter/chain upgrade may be a better long term investment. The transmissions I'm thinking about are: Shimano CUES and Microshift Advent/Advent X. Acera was used in 2019 because it was a cheap derailleur and it was available, but it has not been designed for single chainring ebikes (same for the M592, released in 2009, modern single chainrings did not exist).

Thanks for that tidbit. Good to know going forward. I looked up the CUES in the spread sheet I linked in my answer.  They all have a 1.1 pull ratio. My setup is all 1.7. So I think I’d have to change out more things to properly switch to CUES

You will indeed need to change the shifter as well, as I mentioned, but it's not very expensive (30€ for a U6000 - Acera is equivalent to U4000). The pull ratio only matters if you want to mix up families of products, but a shifter/derailleur of the same family, they will work. The gain is a nicer shifter operation (less effort to shift, and the index shifter works in both directions, so you can use it with your thumb as well — important for me, because I like to keep the index on the brake), more accurate shifting, more durability. And it opens also the possibility of using larger cassettes

It looks long cage to me, any long cage Shimano 9speed will drop in. To know if a medium cage will work look at the Capacity specification for the derailleur and work out you drive train capacity (Largest chainring - smallest chainring, plus largest cassette cog - smallest cassette cog).
You could also consider other manufacturers - e.g. Microshift do a Shimano compatible 9 speed range, but probably easer to stick to Shimano or the choices get too much.
While going up to a better deraileur will never hurt, don't expect big differences, the derailleur is just one part of a complex system.  When I have a replacement such as this, I shop for the biggest discount component that meets spec without getting silly on upgrade. Usuaully I can find a couple of grades higher at no (or small) premium over replacing like for like.

I found this spreadsheet (below) which helped a ton. You are correct I think it is a long cage (SGS). So I ordered a Deore RD-M592-SGS which was $50 instead of $30. My time is the biggest cost.
The derailleur that was on there stopped working. I only want to avoid that happening again prematurely. Be thrilled if it works the same but just lasts longer. I also bought a Shimano optislick cable outer and inner.
I learned that matching the 1.7 pull ratio is the most critical to match. I also stayed with the same cage size, mtb and brand. That narrowed it down a lot.
I copied the file locally and used excel to do multiple filters at once. I couldn’t figure out how to do that on google sheets
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16C3Rz6qmzmurSNd-L3IeMSFukkBFV6D1DRbfS59EDrE/edit#gid=847158527
